# I am confused between two statements, which one of them will be true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The two statements are:
$$\forall A : \varnothing \in \big(\mathcal P(A) \setminus \varnothing\big)$$
$$\forall A : \varnothing \subseteq \big(\mathcal P(A) \setminus \varnothing\big)$$

Where $\varnothing$ is the null set and $\mathcal P(A)$ is the power set of $A$. Any help will be much appreciated! TIA

Anmol

Comment: Hi Anmol, welcome to MSE. What's $\varphi$?

Comment: What is $ \phi $ ?

Comment: I am so sorry! I should have mentioned it (it is a null set). Updated.

Comment: Thank you @DuncanRamage :)

Comment: So it is P(A) minus φ @Physor

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi$ is the empty set then *both* statements are true. The second statement is automatically true, as the emptyset is vacuously a subset of every set. The first statement is also true, as $\varphi \subseteq A$ for every set. So, $\varphi \in P(A)$. Since $P(A) - \varphi = P(A)$, $\varphi \in P(A) - \varphi$

This answer comes with a caveat though: you may have meant to have written $P(A) - \{\varphi\}$ in both statements. If this is the case, then the former statement will no longer be true.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Much appreciated!

Comment: Since I am new to the site, I wanted to know if there is a limit of asking questions. Because I do have doubts in quite a few (logical) kind of questions, and I do not want to bother/spam the forum.

Comment: @AnmolAggarwal As a new user, you have a built in limit to how fast you can ask questions. Aside from this though, there is no hard and fast rule about how many questions you can ask. The fact that you are concerned about bothering the forum tells me you won't actually end up bothering anyone.

Comment: @AnmolAggarwal As a tip though, questions where you show what work/thoughts you have already done/have will be much more well received.

Comment: That is good to know @duncan ramage. I will keep these things in mind. :)